# error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, nodejs, docker, composer

Hola al querer contruir mi docker me sale este error de una libreria de python alguien que me diga que puedo hacer mi SO es manjaro

Answer (score 0):

master:

¿Tendrás instalado libpython3.6? Si la respuesta es no, intenta:

```
sudo pacman -Syy
sudo pacman -S libpython3.6-dev
```

En caso de tenerlo instalado, también podrías hacer un export de la ruta donde sustituyes /ruta/libpython.so por la ruta verdadera del .so en tu equipo:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/ruta/libpython.so
```

Comment: Instante instalarlo pero me dice que que no se ah encontrado el paquete

Comment: Sound likes it doesn't have python dev packages like Arch.

You can try install python-dev-tools with pip https://github.com/vpoulailleau/python-dev-tools/ :

Install pip:

`pacman -S python-pip`

In my case the default is:
`[root@892c27ed9f4d /]# whereis pip`
`pip: /usr/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip`

And install python-dev-tools: 
`pip install python-dev-tools`

Installed:

`[root@892c27ed9f4d /]# pip list  | grep dev-tools`
`python-dev-tools              2020.2.5`